# How can a drop down dynaically change a web app?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am working with a Google App Script web app that is going to be used to display student micro-credentials. The goal is to make it so I can use a dropdown to choose which classes are displayed. I have created the dropdown on the web app by copying from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp), but it doesn't actually function. I need some help getting the dropdown to do what I need it today.

In the example screen you can see the view I have set up and the dropdown with three classes:
[image: Web app with dropdown]

The data for this web app is stored on a Google Sheet, like this:
[image: Data]

And the doGet looks like this:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('WebApp');
  var pictures = getPictures(classSelection);
  var names = getNames(classSelection);
  var cutBelts = getCutBelts(classSelection);
  var measureBelts = getMeasureBelts(classSelection);
  var bindBelts = getBindBelts(classSelection);

  var classSize = 10;

  if(pictures.length<10){
    classSize=pictures.length;
  }


  htmlOutput.pictures = pictures;
  htmlOutput.names = names;
  htmlOutput.cutBelts = cutBelts;
  htmlOutput.measureBelts = measureBelts;
  htmlOutput.bindBelts = bindBelts;
  htmlOutput.classSize = classSize;

  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}
```

Where the variable "classSelection" is equal to the name of the class (101, 201, or 202) and the five 'get' functions (getPictures, getNames) return the picture, names, etc for that class as an array.

Okay, so here is my specific issue I need help with.

1. How do I get the dropdown to send data (the class) back to the doGet so that the variable "classSelection" updates and displays only the selected class?

Again, for the code I used to create the dropdown (html, css, and script) see [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp), I literally copy-pasted and only changed the drop down titles

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using a webapp.  I probably would have just use a dialog and a select element attached to a function with an event listener and communicated server side with google.script.run.  The short answer to you question is use a post or a get to return the data to the webapp endpoint via the webapps url.

Comment: That’s what I use for my project.  When page load , call backend  google.script.run function return data. Then use js event listening to change the data in the html tags.   I can share you a sample code later.

Comment: @liquidkat ... why not use templated html and load it server side with evaluate()?

Comment: @liquidkat and Cooper,
Can either of you share some more details or example code related to this? I have done close to zero with the html/webapp side of Apps Script. All of my experience is with the hidden side data management, so this is my first attempt at making a user-interface, so I'm just grasping at straws. If there is a better way, I'm all ears, but keep in mind I'm a self-taught and novice coder :)

Comment: Hi there @LeeJones! [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) you can check an HTML template guide. Ideally you could evaluate the `classSelection` variable with a scriptlet inside the template. Then you could use [`HtmlTemplate.evaluate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template#evaluate) to transform the template to an `HtmlOutput`. Please test this approach and write back sharing your findings.